# Automatically enabling all ethernet, ATA, SATA, and SCSI drivers in the Linux .config file

Tags: linux

I am compiling my own Linux kernel and userland tools for a PXE environment meant for cloning and reimaging.  Right now, I'm sticking to a specific kernel version and using preconfigured .config's for building the Linux kernel.

I need to change from using preconfigured .config's to automatically generating the default configuration for the specified architecture, and then enabling all ethernet, ATA, SATA, and SCSI drivers.

The reason I want to do this is:

- Updating the kernel means updating the preconfigured .config's, which takes too much time to manually do.  The way I'm doing it now is using menuconfig, enabling the options I need, and saving the resulting .config to my repository.
- I know the kernel I'm building is missing some drivers because I've encountered some PC's that were not able to mount the NFS share because Linux could not find an ethernet device (which I've verified by booting an Ubuntu CD, which did find the ethernet device).  I want an automated way of building any Linux kernel version that will guarantee that ALL drivers I need are pulled in.
- Using a distribution's configuration pulls in too many unnecessary drivers and features for my purposes.  It lengthens the kernel build time from 10-15 mintues to an hour or more, and the resulting image is too big.

Does anyone know how to write a Bash script to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a text editor to modify the `.config` file.

Then you can modify it using search and replace.

Plus, there are other choices for configuring the kernel than the menu-driven "menuconfig".

Comment: The idea is to stop editing the .config directly altogether.  I would like to have an initial .config generated from `make defconfig` and the driver types I mentioned added from a script.

Comment: Try writing a script (e.g. `sed` or `awk`) that modifies the `.config` as you desire.